# RealityKit AR Directions

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

Is it possible to make like an AR GPS type thing using RealityKit? Kind of like the lines that appear on the road in Watch Dogs.

I’m having an issue figuring out how to place objects in the correct direction. For example, I’m trying to make a line that goes straight towards the north pole, so you’d have to point your camera in that direction on the ground to see the line. Is this possible? My entity is always placed wherever the camera is pointed at. How do I place it in a predetermined position?

Answer (score 1):

I learned a lot about that kind of thing from working through these examples on GitHub:

https://github.com/vasile/ARKit-CompassRose

https://github.com/ProjectDent/ARKit-CoreLocation

Neither is very recent, but all the concepts are there.